# Graphics error in orthogonal trajectory

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, computational-geometry

[OT_Circles/Tractrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3164951/orthogonal-trajectories-of-circles-centered-on-x-axis)

To find an orthogonal trajectory we generally replace slope  by its negative reciprocal in its originating differential equation (DE). I.e., replacing $\phi\rightarrow \pi/2-\phi $

DEs of sphere and pseudosphere meridians are respectively:

$$ \cos\phi= r/a; \quad \sin \phi= r/a; $$

To plot meridians the DEs can be conveniently expressed as product of principal curvatures (primed on $z$-axis variable).

$$ \dfrac {r^{''}}{  r (1+r^{'2})^2}=\pm \frac{1}{a^2}$$

I attempted to draw the two meridians with NDSolve choosing an orthogonal intersection at starting point.

```
Clear["`.*"]
a = 1; sgn = -1; zmax = 1.5999;
ri = 0.8; slp = Sqrt[1 - ri^2]/ri ; ar = 0.5;
NDSolve[{R''[z]/R[z]/(1 + R'[z]^2)^2 == sgn 1/a^2, R'[0] == slp, 
   R[0] == ri}, R, {z, 0, zmax}];
r[t_] = R[t] /. First[%];
sph = Plot[{r[z], 0}, {z, 0, zmax}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick}, 
   PlotLabel -> "SPH", AspectRatio -> ar, GridLines -> Automatic];
"~~~    change of sign of gauss curvature   ~~~  "
sgn = +1;
NDSolve[{R''[z]/R[z]/(1 + R'[z]^2)^2 == sgn 1/a^2, R[0] == ri, 
   R'[0] == -1/slp}, R, {z, 0, zmax}];
r[t_] = R[t] /. First[%];
ps = Plot[{r[z], 0}, {z, 0, zmax 1.1}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Thick}, 
   PlotLabel -> "PS & SPH", AspectRatio -> ar, GridLines -> Automatic];
Show[{ps, sph}, PlotRange -> All]
```

However the second intersection the does not appear convincingly to be orthogonal. This is accentuated in the second figure where tractrix and circle are orthogonal at the first point (cusp and maximum point respectively) but not the intersection at right or second point.

EDIT 1:

Am not able to trace my error. It appears to me that a family of orthogonal trajectories (unit parameter $a$ circles and tractrices on x-axis) can be computed *but not drawn satisfactorily*... perhaps due to inclusion of an unexpected *spurious root* for second intersection point.

Thanks in advance for attention on the frustrating problem.

[image: Tractrix and displaced semicircles]

Comment: "does not appear convincingly to be orthogonal" - then, did you check if the slopes of the two curves at their intersection have the appropriate relationship?

Comment: The slope equality as you suggest checks OK by numerical calculation, However the visible  "secantcy" of a wedge between the green radius and blue tractrix at the right point $ z\approx 1,5906 $ is to me not acceptable. I tried with $ri=0.6$ and visible wedge secantcy persists. At the left point tangency is visibly OK.. I did not expect this in *Mathematica*

Comment: Well, then I would say your setting of `AspectRatio -> 0.5` is suspect. Try `AspectRatio -> Automatic`; if you still do not see the expected right angles, then we have a more interesting problem.

Comment: Actually I did that also, no luck. But I shall get back sir....

Comment: I suspect that you add a constant $0$ in both plots so that the origin of the axes is shown at $(0,0$. You can achieve that more simply by setting `AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}` in your `Plot` or in your `Show`.

Comment: I started at $z=0$ for either range and plotted $r=0$ line for both plots to take care of that  Also no change noted by common datum origin as above.

Comment: Changed first point to include symmetry. The non-orthogonality at second point is (even visible) striking. There is no graphics issue here.

Comment: It is now to me an established and unexplained fact that only one of two intersection is in fact orthogonal.